# clCreateFromGLBuffer crash

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl, sfml, vbo

When I tried to use my vbo with opencl I get a crash when calling clCreateFromGLBuffer

Below a small code that reproduce the issue:

initialisation of the opengl context

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 2;
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(2048, 1024), "GAME",
        sf::Style::Fullscreen, settings);
glewInit();
```

initialisation of the opencl context

```
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);

ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id,
        &ret_num_devices);

cl_context_properties props[] = { CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR,
        (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentContext(), CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,
        (cl_context_properties) wglGetCurrentDC(), CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties) platform_id, 0 };

cl_context context = clCreateContext(props, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL,
        &ret);

GLuint vboID_m = 0;
```

Creation of the vertex buffer object

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vboID_m);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID_m);
{

    std::vector<float> tmp = { 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. };

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (tmp.size()) * sizeof(float), 0,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, tmp.size() * sizeof(float),
            tmp.data());
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glFlush();
```

Linkage of the opencl buffer with the opengl vertex buffer object

```
cl_int status;
clCreateFromGLBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, vboID_m, &status);
return 0;
```

Comment: Without looking at the details, I suggest you do some error checking both on the OpenGL and OpenCL side to narrow down the issue. When there's a crash, often there has been an error earlier that was ignored.

Comment: I don't see any error prior to the clCreateFromGLBuffer function :(

Comment: by errors, I assume @w-m means check return values/`glGetError()` effects of all the CL/GL API calls. Have you done that?

Comment: yes and all of them return 0 either glGetError or the return values of clGetDeviceIDs and clCreateContext

Answer (score 0):

When I check the value of ret_num_devices, I get 2. If I change the code to get the platform id for the second device, every things works fine. So I am wondering if the problem is : The opengl context is created for the second platform (my graphic card) and I was trying to access the gpu of my cpu (first platform).

If this is true, Can you explain me how to retrieve the platform that correspond to the one used by opengl ?